# Unable to connect to Firebase cloud messaging my Ionic capacitor android application

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging, capacitor

Recently, i’ve generated an android application which is not a native android application. I have used the ionic framework to export a VUE JS web project to an android application. Mostly of functions are working correctly, but i’ve been unable to implement push notifications with firebase.

I’ve followed the steps recommended in the firebase official documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

My project specifications are these:
[variables Gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhOyu.png)

Tried to connect my Android app to Firebase using both of the following options:
• First: Using the Firebase console setup workflow. (I'm able to get the FCM registration token but none of the notifications i send reach my app in the background)
• Second: Using the Android Studio Firebase Assistant.
[Firebase assistant in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skhd2.png)

After trying to connect to Firebase, it gives the following error:
[Resolve Gradle build issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2yXR.png)

[Android Gradle plugin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prhd5.png)

[Modules properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLxBX.png)

I’ve been tried every tutorial I’ve found but they always work over native apps, so I created a native android app to configure the notifications with firebase and it worked. I think the problem may be some configuration I’m missing.

Comment: You need to use a Capacitor plugin to implement push notifications, e.g. https://github.com/capawesome-team/capacitor-firebase/blob/main/packages/messaging/README.md